# share input variables across many terraform modules

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-modules

I have two different terraform modules with the same input var, execept for the name and the domain.
Is there a way to share the input var? maybe with an external file or something like that?

Here my modules

```
module "autoscaling_docker_frontend" {
  source = "../../_/autoscaling_docker"

  domain        = "domain-1.com"
  has_keychain  = true
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
  name          = "name-1"

  certificate         = var.certificate
  ami                 = var.ami
  account_id          = var.account_id
  dns_zone_id         = var.dns_zone_id
  environment         = var.environment
  key_name            = var.key_name
  subnets             = var.subnets
  vpc_id              = var.vpc_id
  policies            = var.policies
  region              = var.region
  security_groups_alb = var.security_groups_alb
  security_groups_ec2 = var.security_groups_ec2
}

module "autoscaling_docker_backend" {
  source = "../../_/autoscaling_docker"

  domain        = "domain-2.com"
  has_keychain  = true
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
  name          = "name-2"

  certificate         = var.certificate
  ami                 = var.ami
  account_id          = var.account_id
  dns_zone_id         = var.dns_zone_id
  environment         = var.environment
  key_name            = var.key_name
  subnets             = var.subnets
  vpc_id              = var.vpc_id
  policies            = var.policies
  region              = var.region
  security_groups_alb = var.security_groups_alb
  security_groups_ec2 = var.security_groups_ec2
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "share"? Share how?

Comment: I would like to share all the input var. Put all input vars into a dedicated files and call this file in the module (like we do with "source")

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I haven't had the time to try. I'll try this week. Thank you

Comment: I can't create a common module, because module "autoscaling_docker" requires all those vars to be configured correctly. autoscaling_docker is a common module used everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your common variables see to be networking related. Thus you could create a **dedicated module** for creating of the network environment for your autoscaling group.

This way you would call networking module first and then could pass its all outputs to other modules as an input variable.